# Safari is asking if I want to leave the page when saving my edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, safari

Whenever I edit my own answer, and click Save Edits, I get the dialog confirming that I want to leave the page:

[image]

It should just save my edits as I am trying to save them, not cancel them.

This is happening for me on Safari 5.1 / OSX. **EDIT**: Safari 6.0 now consistently reproduces this problem.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Answer a question.
2. Click "Edit" on your own answer
3. Make a change
4. Click "Save Edit"
5. Get alert asking if it's OK to Leave the page.

I'm not trying to leave the page, I am trying to save an edit to an answer I made.

**EDIT**:

It seems that I am getting a JavaScript error along with this behavior:

```
Type issue
Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

On line 171 of full.js.

**Edit**: As of Safari 6.0 on July 25th it's line 178 of the minified full.js. This will impact anyone that applies security updates to Lion or installs Mountain Lion after today as Safari 6.0 ships for both OS:

> `u[0]])},{sliding:!0});r.keyup(k);i.find("#title,.wmd-input,#tagnames,.edit-comment").keydown(function(b){if(!0===b.ctrlKey&&13==b.keyCode)return s.submit(),!1;if(27==b.keyCode)return a(),j(d),!1});s.submit(function(){var a=$(this).serialize();a.fkey=StackExchange.options.user.fkey;StackExchange.navPrevention&&StackExchange.navPrevention.stop();o.parent().addSpinner();StackExchange.helpers.disableSubmitButton(s);$.ajax({type:"POST",dataType:"json",data:a,url:s[0].action,success:function(a){if(a.success){var c=`

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Rory sorry, just added to question

Comment: Web pages really don't work the way you describe.  There are some programs like Microsoft Access applications that save when you move off a record, but those are Client/Server applications.  Most web pages require you to POST, which generally means pushing a button.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry if I am not making myself clear. Please see my edits.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Anyone?

Comment: @balpha no repro for me....

Comment: @balpha Not happening on Meta, just on SO main site for me.

Comment: The script-loading probably borked during that particular page load or something. (But do scripts ever break partially?)

Comment: @balpha No repro for me either...

Comment: @balpha it came back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140673/extraneous-alert-when-saving-edits

Comment: According to the dupe, this might be an OS X issue.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/github/gollum/issues/414 (but if so, makes this a beta browser issue).

Comment: I've never seen this error on Safari 5.1. It is easily reproducable on any Mountain Lion build of Safari as well as Safari 6 for Lion. Whether the causes of this are the same is uncertain - but with the release of Safari 6 for Lion and Mountain Lion, users are going to see a lot of this dialog as they update.

Comment: @balpha - I saw this before on Safari 5.1 in Lion, but only with the moderator display onscreen. On Safari 6.0 in Mountain Lion, this happens every time I try to make an edit, and as bmike said this seems to be pretty reproducible for other Mountain Lion users. With Mountain Lion rolling out today, I imagine more people will be encountering this.

Comment: @BradLarson Could you F5 and verify the line number that the error message occurs on in the Console? (I assume the one in this report is out of date, and I didn't see anything odd on the line mentioned in one of the other reports)

Comment: @TimStone I've added error details from today to the question (awaiting peer review). Note that as production is using a minified version of the code, the line in question has a lot of code on it (and Safari has no 'prettify' option like Chrome).

Comment: I'd try to help by debugging during the break-on-error, but [I can't](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83267) (grrr…)

Comment: @TimStone - I'm getting the same error as Phrogz is seeing in his above edit, and Safari is breaking on the same line of minified JavaScript.

Comment: @Phrogz Hmm, in the console, if you attempt to do `"".fkey = "test"`, do you get a similar exception?

Comment: @TimStone No, that works just fine. I wonder if the `a` that has that `fkey` property is special in some way.

Comment: @Phrogz Should just be a normal string, since it comes from `serialize()`...though it looks like the code is mistakenly assuming it's an object.

Comment: Web Inspector indeed shows it as a String, but another `a` [as a function too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ9vZ.png), @Tim? Not sure if that's an issue.

Comment: (As an aside, I am not getting the popup when editing an answer in the Formatting Sandbox. But indeed Safari's Web Inspector does break on that line if I have that open.)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue in Safari 6.0 on Mountain Lion. If there is anything further I can do to help debug, just ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tim Stone hit the nail on the head with [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134611/safari-is-asking-if-i-want-to-leave-the-page-when-saving-my-edits#comment399237_134611):

> @Phrogz Should just be a normal string, since it comes from serialize()...though **it looks like the code is mistakenly assuming it's an object.** <sub>*(emph. mine)*</sub>

We were assigning `fkey` (the XSRF token) as a property to a string (the serialization of the edit form). This has three issues:

1. It's unnecessary, because the `fkey` is already included in the serialization, since it's a hidden `input` element of the form.
2. It's useless, because it doesn't do anything – you can't add properties to a string.
3. As you witnessed, it now breaks in Safari with strict mode. It's arguable whether it *should* (according to the definition of strict mode), but it does make a certain amount of sense; the purpose of strict mode is to cause things to fail loudly instead of silently.

Fixed in the next build, and cheers to [Jason Salaz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1346/jason-salaz) for his [debugging help](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5530878#5530878).

Comment: Oh, that actually *was* it? I realised after the fact that my asking them to test the bare statement in the console was silly since it wouldn't have been evaluated in strict mode, heh, but didn't even think to check if the property actually took in non-strict mode. I was thrown a bit by the fact that the specification says string objects are extensible, but I suppose that isn't actually applicable for this case. Well, good that it's fixed!

Comment: @TimStone: String objects aren't strings though, nor the other way around. JavaScript the good parts: Not one of them.

Comment: Right, right. Oh, JavaScript...