# Extraneous alert when saving edits?

Tags: bug, edits, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow is asking if I want to leave the page when saving my edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134611/stack-overflow-is-asking-if-i-want-to-leave-the-page-when-saving-my-edits)

I've recently been prompted to edit several of my answers on Stack Overflow, and when attempting to save them, I get the "are you sure you want to leave the page?" alert.  Clearly, this is inappropriate, because I intended to click "save edits".

[image]

I'm using Safari on Mountain Lion. Safari on Lion doesn't seem to show this problematic alert.

Comment: Please add your details to the existing report; this hasn't been satisfactorily reproduced.

Comment: I have no problems in Safari 5.1.7 on Lion. Or whatever the old OS X is called. Is the new one already out? (Edit: ah, it's in Beta.)