# Bug in Safari 6 when saving an edited answer

Tags: bug, edits, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow is asking if I want to leave the page when saving my edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134611/stack-overflow-is-asking-if-i-want-to-leave-the-page-when-saving-my-edits)

Safari 6 detects the save changes button press as an attempt to navigate away from a page with edited content.

[image]

If you choose **Stay on Page**, the edits remain, but the saving action does not take place. If you choose **Leave Page** the edits are saved. Normally this dialog indicates that you are about to lose the changes you have made.

Mac OS X 10.7.4 and Safari Version 6.0 (7536.25)

Comment: Is it Monday again? I clicked the 'Stay on Page' button on your screen shot five times before I realized it was a screen shot.

Comment: It's creepy how that screenshot doesn't move a pixel when switching between this post and its dupe (well, it was true before the closed banner appeared).

Comment: I did not get this error with Safari 5.1 ever. I do get it with safari 6. I've tested the site on more than 5 macs - so this could be  a different issue than the "dupe" but share the same error message. As long as someone is tracking this I'm happy.

Comment: Goddamn, that message box must be a good six, seven meters off the window below it!  What the hell is holding it up?  Apple, you clever bastards!

Comment: It's actually skitch's shadow porn setting. Evernote bought em - so it should get progressively uglied up with each release B-/