# Clicking "Save Edits" shows "Are you sure you want to leave page" on Safari under OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: bug, safari, osx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow is asking if I want to leave the page when saving my edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134611/stack-overflow-is-asking-if-i-want-to-leave-the-page-when-saving-my-edits)

1. Find a post you made.
2. Click the "Edit" link.

   - *Post enters edit mode (correct)*
3. Make a change to the text of your post
4. Click on "Save Edits"

**EXPECTED**: Form is submitted and changes are seen.
**ACTUAL**: Safari shows the "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" dialog.

[image: Are you sure you want to leave this page? You have started writing or editing a post.]

**Workaround**: Click "Leave Page" to get your edits saved.

OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)
Safari Version 6.0 (8536.25)

Console shows:

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.         full.js:178
```

Comment: Oh this is going to be fun. I'm a grab some peanuts and enjoy the show.

Comment: This was [reported on Safari 5.1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134611/stack-overflow-is-asking-if-i-want-to-leave-the-page-when-saving-my-edits) but not easily reproducible. It's 100% reproducible on [Safari 6.0 on 10.7 Lion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141126/bug-in-safari-6-when-saving-an-edited-answer).

Comment: I thought this was just me, or somehow triggered by the moderator controls being onscreen. I've closed to point to the original issue, but we can hopefully get them to reproduce this now.

Comment: I guess my point is - hundreds of people on the Apple site have never seen this issue on 5.1 before today and we now have pretty much everyone on Safari 6 seeing the bug. My guess is the OP of the original question actually had a beta version of the browser / framework that was posioning the "5.1" version of the app or just plain wrong about the version to make this bug appear.